# Call module or module function using square brackets

Tags: elixir

In Ruby it is possible to call a class or a module using `[]` if you define it like this:

```
class Pair
  def self.[](pair_name)
    ...return pair by name
  end
end
```

is there any equivalent in Elixir that allows you to call a module function by square(curly/round) brackets?

I'd like to have a short alias for a method to avoid calls like this:
`Pair.from_name(pair_name)` and do something like this `Pair.[pair_name]`.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question correctly: do you want to define a `[]` function on a module in general, or do you want to use `[]` with a custom struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest possible syntax that I found in Elixir.
It's possible to define a module method using curly braces and then using it like this: `:atom.{}`

```
defmodule Pair do
  defstruct [:id]

  def {pair_name}, do: %Pair{id: from_name(pair_name)}
  def from_name(_), do: 1
end
```

Usage:

`Pair.{"some_name"} => %Pair{id: 1}`

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no such functionality in elixir AFAIK.

However, if you would like to use shorter function names, why not utilize pattern matching, guards and `import`:

```
defmodule Pair do
  defstruct name: "Default"

  def pair(name) when is_bitstring(name), do: %Pair{name: name}
  def pair(id) when is_integer(id), do: %Pair{name: "#{id}"}
end
```

---

```
iex(1)> import Pair, only: [pair: 1]
Pair
iex(2)> pair("what")
%Pair{name: "what"}
iex(3)> pair(3)
%Pair{name: "3"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was hoping to be proven wrong, but I have to conclude that it's not possible. I've messed around with a few things, and it doesn't seem to be possible.

From [the documentation of `Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html):

> Note that the dynamic lookup syntax (`term[key]`) roughly
>   translates to `Access.get(term, key, nil)`.

So if we want to get bracket syntax to work, we'll need to hook into `Access.get` somehow. Taking a look at the [source code for `Access.get`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6.6/lib/elixir/lib/access.ex#L295), we see that it has

> ```
> def get(container, key, default \\ nil)
> def get(%module{} = container, key, default)                    # (1)
> def get(map, key, default) when is_map(map)                     # (2)
> def get(list, key, default) when is_list(list) and is_atom(key) # (3)
> def get(list, key, _default) when is_list(list)                 # (4)
> def get(nil, _key, default)                                     # (5)
> ```

Let's break these down. The top line is just the prototype, so it doesn't tell us much. (2), (3), and (4) only apply on lists and maps, and (5) is a safeguard to make nils more convenient. (1) is the only one that could feasibly work with us; if `container` is a structure type (as from a module), then we could hook into the behavior by adopting the `Access` behavior in our own module. However, this is where we hit a brick wall. If we go into the interpreter and ask it exactly *what* a module's name is, we encounter a problem.

```
iex(1)> defmodule Foo do end
{:module, Foo, ...}
iex(2)> i Foo
Term
  Foo
Data type
  Atom
...
```

So the module's name is just an atom. In Ruby, classes are instances of the `Class` class, so they can have modifications made on them fairly liberally. However, in Elixir, `Foo` is just an atom (a symbol, in Ruby's terminology), and none of the `Access.get` cases work with an atom as the first argument.

I'd love to be proven wrong on this, but from what I can tell, I can say with a decent amount of certainty that it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, so this answer might not be what you were looking for.*

---

In Elixir the `[]` syntax is reserved for data structures and is basically a shortcut to `Access.get/2`. By default `[]` does not work on custom structs but there is a way to "teach" `Access` how to handle your own structs. For this you need to implement the `Access` behaviour.

### Example

Let's assume we have this custom `MyContainer` struct:

```
defmodule MyContainer do
  defstruct contained: %{}
end
```

And we want to be able to access fields in the `contained` map by simply doing `container[:foo]`. For this we need to implement the `Access` behaviour.

```
defmodule MyContainer do
  defstruct contained: %{}

  @behaviour Access

  def fetch(%__MODULE__{contained: map}, key) do
    Access.fetch(map, key)
  end

  def get(%__MODULE__{contained: map}, key, default) do
    Access.get(map, key, default)
  end

  def get_and_update(%__MODULE__{contained: map}, key, update_fn) do
    Access.get_and_update(map, key, update_fn)
  end

  def pop(%__MODULE__{contained: map}, key) do
    Access.pop(map, key)
  end
end
```

Now we can do the following:

```
iex> my_map = %{foo: "bar"}
iex> my_container = %MyContainer{contained: my_map}
iex> my_container[:foo]
"bar"
```